# How to store the image path to SQlite database and retrive it to show in an imgeView

Tags: android, sqlite

I  want to store the image path to the SQlite database and later retrieve it to populate in a listView.

Here is my code below . The problem is ImageView is not populating after saving the  image path in the database.

Code for geting the image Uri from the gallery and get the Image path

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
     data) {

     if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (data != null){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri);
            itemImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
            itemImage.invalidate();
        }
    }
    }

    //Method to get the image path from the Uri
    public String getImagePath(Uri currentUri){
    String path = "no-path-found";
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(currentUri, projection, null,
            null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_Index = 
    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        path = cursor.getString(column_Index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

And this is the code to insert the image Path to the db :

```
    private void insertItem(){

    //Get a writable database
    SQLiteDatabase database = itemDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Uri mUri;

    //Get values from the fields from user
    String name = itemName.getText().toString().trim();
    imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri).trim();

    //Create a content values object to insert items
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ItemEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(ItemEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE, imagePath);
```

Then I use a Cursor Adapter class to populate the views :

```
    public class ItemCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ItemCursorAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, null, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, 
    false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

    //Fetching the values from the cursor
    String name = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
    String image = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE));

    File file = new File(image);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    //Populate the views
    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    textView.setText(name);
}
```

}

Here is the list_item xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    tools:text="Name"/></LinearLayout>
```

How can I get the path saved in the database and populate the image in the imageView?

Comment: Thanks but I've already solved the problem

Comment: @pskink I've stored the imagePath in File and then convert it to bitmap by :  Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File file = new File(image);
        if (file.exists()) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds =true;
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0):

Try this one i have implemented this one.
1st Table field is `BLOB` like `img_driver BLOB`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
encImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

2nd Image convert into `Base64` format.
This process is store image in `Sqlite` database.

**Now fetch Image from `SqLite` database.**

1st When you fetch image that a time fetch into `String`

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(arr_image.get(0).getImg_driver(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
iv_sign.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

`Base64` string to convert into decode into `byte array`
And you can set image in `ImageView`